# Common Lisp: Execute a form until nil

Tags: loops, common-lisp

I'd like to execute a CL form until it becomes nil. How can I?
(I RTFM, but couldn't find it. Maybe I'm just near to mental breakdown).

Anyway, help would be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(loop while your-form)
```

or

```
(do () ((not your-form)))
```